# Accessing IExplorer through a proxy for the first time using WebRequest error

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, webrequest

I am trying to access internet explorer with a proxy for the first time in C# by using WebRequest..

the idea behind the app is that you can access website through IExplorer with a proxy that you enter in textbox (as shown below)

I tried my method out but it connects to the website for a brief second and shows my normal ip (not the proxy one) and then it crashes and its gives me this error (down below)

Not sure whats causing it and / or how to fix it.. Was thinking that maybe someone with experience would be able to understand this better than me since its my first time working with proxies in C#

[image]

[image]

```
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(browserNavigationTxtBox.Text);
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.whatsmyip.org/");
        var myproxy = new WebProxy(proxyBox.Text, false);
        request.Proxy = myproxy;
        request.Method = "GET";
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(browserNavigationTxtBox.Text);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy(v=vs.110).aspx), you need a *uri* for the proxy, not just an IP and port. Try `http://180.175.16.228:8118/` instead.

Comment: @CharlesMager Looks like the app only freezes when I try that or crashes and gives the same error, but I'l keep that in mind when using the proxy next time, it was actually a really good tip!

Answer (score 1):

Although you can change the registry values programmatically to set a proxy

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer
>   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyOverride

I would use [FiddlerCore](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore)
to setup my proxy to have more control over what is sent and received (and to be able to use socks proxies).

```
MyProxy.Start();
webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
```

---

```
public class MyProxy
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest;
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8888, true, true);
    }

    static void FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest(Fiddler.Session oSession)
    {
        oSession["X-OverrideGateway"] = "94.76.117.14:8080"; // <-- Your Http Proxy
        //oSession["x-OverrideGateway"] = "socks=ip:port"; //For socks proxy 
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.WriteLine(oSession.fullUrl);
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant I change oSession["X-OverrideGateway"] = "94.76.117.14:8080"; to the value of my textbox?

Comment: @Alexander.Matt How about testing it by yourself, and sharing the result here?

Comment: I did and my textbox isnt popping up in intellisense

Comment: Severity An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.proxyBox

Comment: I tried doing it like this
oSession["X-OverrideGateway"] = proxyBox.Text;

Comment: @Alexander.Matt pass the value `proxyBox.Text` to the `Start` method, store it in a static field and use that field in `FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest` method...